# R: error in read.table, duplicate row.names not allowed despite row.names=NULL

Tags: r

Sorry this is my first message, I am totally new in R and coding in general.

I have a problem with my code. I have this error:

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>   duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

```
  pollutantmean<-function(directory,pollutant,id=1:332){
  files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE) 
  dat <- data.frame() 
  len<-length(files_list)

     for (i in 1:len) {                                
          dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]),row.names = NULL)
         }
  dat_subset <- dat[which(dat[,"ID"] == id),] 
     if(pollutant=="sulfate")
         mean(dat[, "sulfate"], na.rm=TRUE) 
     else
         mean(dat[, "nitrate"], na.rm=TRUE) 
   }
```

I have found the tip `row.names=NULL`, but it doesn't work and I am totally stuck. Many thanks in advance if somebody can help.

Comment: I think the tip is to add `row.names =NULL` inside the parenthesis for read.csv. i.e. `rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i], row.names=NULL))`

Comment: @warmoverflow: Many thanks for your help! I have tried, I don't have the duplicate rows error anymore, but I have this one now:**Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match **. I don't understand why it has an impact on the number of columns of arguments. Does somebody has an idea? I have find a solution to fix it, but I don't undertand the reason of the error.

Comment: Are files identical to each other in terms of columns? Could you post a sample of your file content?

Comment: Ok I get it! Many thanks for your time and your help!